# MonoTouch Dialog--Null Navigation Controller

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, monotouch.dialog

I am looking for a way to change screens when the `GlassButton` is clicked.  I have just started learning Monotouch.Dialog.  I have done the following to try and handle this.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {

        button.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
            this.NavigationController.PushViewController(list, true);
        };
    }
```

list is a `UIViewController`, but on click, `this.NavigationController.PushViewController(list, true);` is pointed to with a null reference exception.  `list` has been instantiated and is not null, however, `this.NavigationController` is null.  How can I fix this?

```
GlassButton button = new GlassButton (new RectangleF(0, 0, 200, 50));
List list = new List ();
public static EntryElement lastName = new EntryElement (null, "Enter Last Name", null);
public static EntryElement firstName = new EntryElement (null, "Enter First Name", null);
public static EntryElement middleInitial = new EntryElement (null, "Enter Middle Initial", null);

    public practice () : base (UITableViewStyle.Grouped, null)
    {
        Root = new RootElement ("Level 1") {
            new Section() {
                new RootElement("Level 2") {
                    new Section("Individual Information") {
                        lastName, firstName, middleInitial
                    },

                    new Section("Submit") {
                        button
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolve by deriving subclass from `DialogViewController`

```
public class CustomDialogViewController : DialogViewController
{
        public CustomDialogViewController(RootElement root)
            : base(null, true)
        {
            base.Root = root;
        }
}
```

In my main view controller i used following in my ViewDidLoad():

```
var root = new RootElement("Customer form");
// code to generate section and add into root
CustomDialogViewController customDialogViewController = new CustomDialogViewController(root);
var navigationController = new UINavigationController(customDialogViewController);

this.AddChildViewController(this.navigationController);
this.View.AddSubview(this.navigationController.View);
```